# get list of dictionaries by combining values of on key based on value of another key

Tags: python

I have a list `[{"a":11, "b":2}, {"a":12, "b":2}, {"a":13, "b":3}, {"a":14, "b":4}]`

I want to combine values of `a` based on values of `b`

I want output as `[{'a':[11, 12], 'b':2}, {'a':[13], 'b':3}, {'a':[14], 'b':4}]`

I have tried `[{ k:list(set([d[k] for d in a])) for k in a[0] } for i in a]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @R.Arctor I have updated the question

Comment: Do you want to combine only the consecutive values of b, or this does not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an intermediary dict to map values of `b` to a sub-list of the values of `a`, and then use a list comprehension that outputs the items of the intermediary dict as a dict with keys as 'b' and values as 'a':

```
mapping = {}
for d in lst:
    mapping.setdefault(d['b'], []).append(d['a'])
[{'a': v, 'b': k} for k, v in mapping.items()]
```

This returns:

```
[{'a': [11, 12], 'b': 2}, {'a': [13], 'b': 3}, {'a': [14], 'b': 4}]
```